# transform a tsv file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm facing a problem since last week with my tsv that I would like to modify and transform into a pandas dataframe.

My file looks like this :

```
'NC_011745.1_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 EaaA, EibA : 3.1'],
                             ['PAI 2 EaaA : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 3 Capsule : 4.428571428571429'],
                             ['PAI 4 EaaA : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 5 ipaH : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 6 IreA, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha) : '
                              '0.96875'],
                             ['PAI 7 IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), Aerobactin : '
                              '0.8157894736842105'],
                             ['PAI 8 MsbB2, VirK : 2.8181818181818183'],
                             ['PAI 9 Antigen 43, AIDA-I type : '
                              '1.3478260869565217']],
 'NC_017632_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 Capsule : 15.857142857142858'],
                           ['PAI 2 AAI/SCI-II, direct heme uptake system, '
                            'Colibactin, Colibactin : 1.819672131147541'],
                           ['PAI 3 F9-like fimbriae, Type 1 fimbriae : '
                            '3.3636363636363638'],
                           ['PAI 4 Ferrous iron transport : 5.045454545454546'],
                           ['PAI 5 Cah, AIDA-I type, Salmochelin, S fimbriae : '
                            '2.707317073170732'],
                           ['PAI 6 ECP, Tsh : 13.875'],
                           ['PAI 7 ACE/AEC T6SS : 9.25'],
                           ['PAI 8 Tia/Hek, P fimbriae, F17-like fimbriae, '
                            'AAI/SCI-II, CNF-1, Alpha-hemolysin, '
                            'hemagglutinin-like adhesin : 1.088235294117647']],
 'NC_017646_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 Allantion utilization : 5.285714285714286'],
                           ['PAI 2 direct heme uptake system : 4.44'],
                           ['PAI 3 ipaH : 27.75'],
                           ['PAI 4 P fimbriae, Aerobactin, Sat, IrgA homolog '
                            'adhesin (Iha), K1 capsule, K1 capsule, T2SS : '
                            '1.3058823529411765'],
                           ['PAI 5 P fimbriae, Tia/Hek : 5.842105263157895'],
                           ['PAI 6 VirK, MsbB2 : 10.090909090909092']]}
```

And I would like to modify and export it as a pandas dataframe like this :

```
\             EaaA, EibA   EaaA   Capsule    ipaH    IreA, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha)  ...
NC_011745.1     3.1        7.75    4.4285..  7.75                0.96875
NC_017632        NA         NA     15.8574   NA                  NA
```

The main problem for me is to put it as a dataframe, I tried :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict]).T
df.to_tsv()
```

but it says that this fucntion is not working with tsv but with csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box with pandas - pandas is good, but it isn't magic. You're going to need to do a lot of manipulation before your data is ready for a dataframe in the format that you want. Try something like this:

```
_dict={'NC_011745.1_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 EaaA, EibA : 3.1'],
                             ['PAI 2 EaaA : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 3 Capsule : 4.428571428571429'],
                             ['PAI 4 EaaA : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 5 ipaH : 7.75'],
                             ['PAI 6 IreA, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha) : '
                              '0.96875'],
                             ['PAI 7 IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), Aerobactin : '
                              '0.8157894736842105'],
                             ['PAI 8 MsbB2, VirK : 2.8181818181818183'],
                             ['PAI 9 Antigen 43, AIDA-I type : '
                              '1.3478260869565217']],
 'NC_017632_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 Capsule : 15.857142857142858'],
                           ['PAI 2 AAI/SCI-II, direct heme uptake system, '
                            'Colibactin, Colibactin : 1.819672131147541'],
                           ['PAI 3 F9-like fimbriae, Type 1 fimbriae : '
                            '3.3636363636363638'],
                           ['PAI 4 Ferrous iron transport : 5.045454545454546'],
                           ['PAI 5 Cah, AIDA-I type, Salmochelin, S fimbriae : '
                            '2.707317073170732'],
                           ['PAI 6 ECP, Tsh : 13.875'],
                           ['PAI 7 ACE/AEC T6SS : 9.25'],
                           ['PAI 8 Tia/Hek, P fimbriae, F17-like fimbriae, '
                            'AAI/SCI-II, CNF-1, Alpha-hemolysin, '
                            'hemagglutinin-like adhesin : 1.088235294117647']],
 'NC_017646_islands.csv': [['PAI 1 Allantion utilization : 5.285714285714286'],
                           ['PAI 2 direct heme uptake system : 4.44'],
                           ['PAI 3 ipaH : 27.75'],
                           ['PAI 4 P fimbriae, Aerobactin, Sat, IrgA homolog '
                            'adhesin (Iha), K1 capsule, K1 capsule, T2SS : '
                            '1.3058823529411765'],
                           ['PAI 5 P fimbriae, Tia/Hek : 5.842105263157895'],
                           ['PAI 6 VirK, MsbB2 : 10.090909090909092']]}


f = {}
for key, a in _dict.items():
    e = {}
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            d = c.split(" : ")
            d[0] = d[0].replace("PAI ", "")[2:]
            d = {d[0]:d[1]}
            e = {**e, **d}
    f[key] = e

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(f, 'index')
```

You'll need to work out a robust method for parsing your strings - probably regex - but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you explain me what {**e, **d} means ?

Comment: See this question for a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The looping answer has already been accepted in @bm13563's dictionary format.' I have responded with 'pandas'.

1. since the data is in list format, create a data frame.
2. Remove parentheses and split columns by ':'.
3. connect vertically to an empty data frame.
4. group them by file name and format them.

```
import pandas as pd

lst_a = [['PAI 1 EaaA, EibA : 3.1'],['PAI 2 EaaA : 7.75'],['PAI 3 Capsule : 4.428571428571429'],['PAI 4 EaaA : 7.75'],['PAI 5 ipaH : 7.75'],['PAI 6 IreA, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha) : ' '0.96875'],['PAI 7 IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), Aerobactin : ' '0.8157894736842105'],['PAI 8 MsbB2, VirK : 2.8181818181818183'],['PAI 9 Antigen 43, AIDA-I type : ' '1.3478260869565217']]
lst_b = [['PAI 1 Capsule : 15.857142857142858'],['PAI 2 AAI/SCI-II, direct heme uptake system, Colibactin, Colibactin : 1.819672131147541'],['PAI 3 F9-like fimbriae, Type 1 fimbriae : 3.3636363636363638'],['PAI 4 Ferrous iron transport : 5.045454545454546'],['PAI 5 Cah, AIDA-I type, Salmochelin, S fimbriae : 2.707317073170732'],['PAI 6 ECP, Tsh : 13.875'],['PAI 7 ACE/AEC T6SS : 9.25'],['PAI 8 Tia/Hek, P fimbriae, F17-like fimbriae, AAI/SCI-II, CNF-1, Alpha-hemolysin, hemagglutinin-like adhesin : 1.088235294117647']]
lst_c = [['PAI 1 Allantion utilization : 5.285714285714286'],['PAI 2 direct heme uptake system : 4.44'],['PAI 3 ipaH : 27.75'],['PAI 4 P fimbriae, Aerobactin, Sat, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), K1 capsule, K1 capsule, T2SS : 1.3058823529411765'],['PAI 5 P fimbriae, Tia/Hek : 5.842105263157895'],['PAI 6 VirK, MsbB2 : 10.090909090909092']]

all_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['col_name', 'value', 'file_name'])

filenames = ['NC_011745.1','NC_017632','NC_017646']
d_lists = [lst_a,lst_b,lst_c]

for k in range(len(d_lists)):
    df = pd.DataFrame({filenames[k]:d_lists[k]})
    df = df.astype(str)
    df[filenames[k]] = df[filenames[k]].str.replace("^\['|'\]$", "")
    df = df[filenames[k]].str.split(' : ', expand=True)
    df.columns = ['col_name','value']
    df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: x[6:])
    df['file_name'] = filenames[k]
    all_df = all_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    i += 1

all_df['value'] = all_df['value'].astype('float')
all_df.groupby(['file_name','col_name'])['value'].sum().unstack()

col_name    AAI/SCI-II, direct heme uptake system, Colibactin, Colibactin   ACE/AEC T6SS    Allantion utilization   Antigen 43, AIDA-I type Cah, AIDA-I type, Salmochelin, S fimbriae   Capsule ECP, Tsh    EaaA    EaaA, EibA  F9-like fimbriae, Type 1 fimbriae   Ferrous iron transport  IreA, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha)    IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), Aerobactin  MsbB2, VirK P fimbriae, Aerobactin, Sat, IrgA homolog adhesin (Iha), K1 capsule, K1 capsule, T2SS   P fimbriae, Tia/Hek Tia/Hek, P fimbriae, F17-like fimbriae, AAI/SCI-II, CNF-1, Alpha-hemolysin, hemagglutinin-like adhesin  VirK, MsbB2 direct heme uptake system   ipaH
file_name                                                                               
NC_011745.1 NaN NaN NaN 1.347826    NaN 4.428571    NaN 15.5    3.1 NaN NaN 0.96875 0.815789    2.818182    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7.75
NC_017632   1.819672    9.25    NaN NaN 2.707317    15.857143   13.875  NaN NaN 3.363636    5.045455    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.088235    NaN NaN NaN
NC_017646   NaN NaN 5.285714    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.305882    5.842105    NaN 10.090909   4.44    27.75
```